# Will vanilla javascript scroll event work on angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to log the offset of window from the top of document but jquery scroll is not working. Will vanilla javascript scroll event listener work in angular?

```
app.directive('owlCarouselItem', function($touch, $timeout, $rootScope, $window){
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        transclude: false,
        link: function(scope, element) {
            // this is the part of my directive the on scroll event is not firing
                $('html, body').on('scroll', function() {
                    if($(this).scrollTop() == 0){
                        console.log($(this).scrollTop());
                        canSwipeDown = true;
                    }else{
                        console.log($(this).scrollTop());
                        canSwipeDown = false;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've done and where in the controller/directive etc you are implementing this? jQuery should work fine to detect scrolling, especially in AngularJS (Not Angular 2)

Comment: why are you using `restrict: C`? are you seriously using `owlCarouselItem` as a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code using angular.element($window):

```
.directive('scrollDir', function($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        link: function(scope, attrs, element) {
            var canSwipeDown = false
            // this is the part of my directive the on scroll event is not firing
            angular.element($window).on('scroll', function() {
                canSwipeDown = element.scrollTop() === 0
                scope.$apply()
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And you can stick directive to body tag
like this 
HTML:

```
<body scroll-dir>
```

Comment: I've improved your code, removed redundancies and added $scope.$apply; event listeners are not part of the angular digest cycle. You should probably explain to the OP how they would consume `canSwipeDown`.